# How to move nodes in java linked simple list?

Tags: java, list, nodes

I have the following problem with a simple java linked list. Which consists of exchanging `nodes`, here the code:

```
    private void swapNodo(Nodo<T> smaller, Nodo<T> current) {
    Nodo<T> previous =this.cab;
    while(previous.getSig()!=current){
        previous=previous.getSig();
    }
    Nodo<T> tmp=previous.getSig();
    current.setSig(smaller.getSig());
    previous.setSig(previous.getSig());
    smaller.setSig(tmp);
}
```

That is why I attached the following image, so that you can understand what I want with that method.
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byG7l.jpg)

To clarify, the exchange only has to be done with `nodes`, that is, their references are nothing more. Since changing the infos I already did it.

I hope someone can help me doing the movement between nodes, thank you very much.

Comment: On a side note, please do not name your method `method`. Try to name something descriptive.

Comment: So you want to sort the LinkedList?

Comment: Hello, If that is what you want to get, the method is insertionSort. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/) But that part of swapping nodes is that it fails me.